# How to share a provisioning profile between 2 developers and use it to distribute an app?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, apple-developer

As a developer I want to know can I use a provisioning profile generated by another developer who has a paid apple developer account to distribute an ios react native app build with expo to apple app store? If so can some explain the steps?

Comment: First, asking how to do something explicitly in contravention of the [license agreement](https://developer.apple.com/programs/apple-developer-program-license-agreement/) of a company is not a good question. Second, Please read about what is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here and what questions you should [avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Using someone else's provisioning profile for distributing your iOS app to the App Store isn't recommended. Each profile is linked to a specific developer account and app, so it's best to create your own to avoid problems.

Now that the fancy disclaimer is out of the way, here are the steps you should follow to distribute an iOS React Native app built with Expo to the Apple App Store:

1. **Apple Developer Account**: Make sure you have your own paid Apple Developer account. This is essential for publishing apps on the App Store.
2. **Expo Build**: Build your React Native app using Expo. You can use the `expo build:ios` command to create a standalone iOS build of your app.
3. **App Identifier**: Ensure that your app has a unique bundle identifier (app identifier). This should match the bundle identifier you've set up in your Apple Developer account.
4. **Provisioning Profile**: Generate a provisioning profile specifically for your app. This profile will include your app's bundle identifier and will be linked to your Apple Developer account. To generate the provisioning profile:

   a. Log in to your Apple Developer account.

   b. Navigate to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section.

   c. Create an App ID with your app's bundle identifier.

   d. Create a distribution certificate (if you haven't already) and use it to generate an App Store provisioning profile. This profile will be associated with your App ID and certificate.
5. **Expo Configuration**: Update your Expo app's configuration to include the correct bundle identifier (matching the one you set up in your Apple Developer account).
6. **Build Configuration**: Run the Expo build command again (`expo build:ios`) with the updated configuration. This will create a new build of your app.
7. **Upload to App Store Connect**: Once the build is ready, upload it to App Store Connect. This is Apple's platform for managing your app's submission process.
8. **App Store Submission**: In App Store Connect, provide all the necessary app information, such as screenshots, app description, keywords, and so on.